# I have input as 123 and output I am looking is 123 123 123 123 123. How to achieve it in Datastage?

Tags: datastage

I have input as 123 and output I am looking is 123 123 123 123 123. How to achieve it in Datastage?

```
input: 123
output :123
        123 
        123
        123
        123
```

Answer (score 0):

The Str() function returns multiples of the input string.
`Str(InLink.MyString, 5)`